# JNativeHook writing the keys to textarea

Tags: java, swing

when keyevents are accured, its printing to the console. but not adding any text to the textarea.

I have a frame here:

```
public class A extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public A() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                         
private void initComponents() {
 //code for components
}                     

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    try {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    }
    catch (NativeHookException ex) {
        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }

    GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    jTextArea1.append("logging started:\n");
}                                        
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new A().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

//calling this method when ever a keyevent is occured. but its not appending any text.
public void getTA(){
    jTextArea1.append("something was pressed");
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

code for globalkeylistener

```
public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
A a;
public GlobalKeyListenerExample(){
  a = new A();
}

public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    a.getTA();
    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}

public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    a.getTA();
    System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}

public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    a.getTA();
    System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
}

}
```

am calling getTA() when an event is occured but nothing is getting appended. any helkp would be great.

Comment: do you want to make 2 frames ? you have a invisible frame and text append to it's textarea

Comment: no. I have a textarea and a button in the frame. and GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample()); is called when I click the button. and if any event occured I want to append "some text" to the textarea.

Comment: test by calling setvisible like `public GlobalKeyListenerExample(){
  a = new A();
  a.setVisible(true);
}` 
then you will see .

Comment: thanks. it works :) but a new window pops up every time :P

Comment: you can answer your own question .

Comment: How can I append the string without opening a new window?

Comment: read my answer to do it without opening new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said you are creating a new object of `class A` in `GlobalKeyListenerExample` class .so you have 2 frame one is visible one is hidden.

when you call  `a.getTA();` you are calling on a object created from following `GlobalKeyListenerExample` class .so you are set text to jtextfield of your invisible frame

```
public  GlobalKeyListenerExample(){
  a = new A();//invisible frame
}
```

so how to fix this .
one way is to implement `NativeKeyListener` to your class `A` without creating a `GlobalKeyListener` class.so you implement all abstract methods like you did in `GlobalKeyListener` class.

and use `GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);` to add listner.

example

```
public class A extends javax.swing.JFrame implements NativeKeyListener {

    public A() {
        initComponents();
    }

    //implement abstract methods  
    @Override
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        a.getTA();
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        a.getTA();
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        a.getTA();
        System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);// add listner
        jTextArea1.append("logging started:\n");
    }

}
```

i can't test this code example.if you have any problem plz ask.

Answer (score 1):

as A extends a frame It is creating a newframe in this part of the code

```
public GlobalKeyListenerExample(){
    a = new A();
}
```

. by setting a.setVisible(true) it is visible and text is appended to the textarea in this frame everytime an event occurs.

```
public GlobalKeyListenerExample(){
    a = new A();
    a.setVisible(true);
}
```

thanks to [fast snail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227526/fast-snail) for helping me out.